# How to load JSON data array into table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I just feel confused in loading the data into a table using jQuery. How properly load data into a table? Just the example table below which is written in JavaScript using the for loop only. I not familiar using the $.each() of jQuery.

JSON Array Data: This is the COLUMN:

```
{
    "data": [
        [
            "ID",
            "TYPE",
            "TOTAL",
            "1 bed room",
            "2 bed room"
        ]
    ]
}
```

JSON Array Data: This is the DATA:

```
{
    "data": [
        [
            "100",
            "Total Transaction Amount",
            "9812355000",
            "23397000",
            "13976000"
        ],
        [
            "100",
            "No. of units",
            "1268",
            "3",
            "2"
        ],
        [
            "100",
            "(Total sq.ft.)",
            "",
            "",
            ""
        ],
        [
            "100",
            "Avg. price",
            "7738450",
            "7799000",
            "6988000"
        ],
        [
            "100",
            "Avg. sq.ft.",
            "",
            "",
            ""
        ],
        [
            "100",
            "Max. price",
            "25494000",
            "9918000",
            "7318000"
        ],
        [
            "100",
            "Max. sq.ft",
            "",
            "",
            ""
        ],
        [
            "100",
            "Min. price",
            "5904000",
            "6465000",
            "6658000"
        ],
        [
            "100",
            "Min. sq.ft",
            "",
            "",
            ""
        ]
    ]
}
```

jQuery Script:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("FlatType", "Home", new {id = ViewBag.Id})",
                async: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    var table = "<tr>";
                    $.each(data.data, function (index, value) {
                        table += "<td>" + value + "</td>";
                        console.log(value);
                    });
                    table += "</tr>";

                    $("#myColumns").html(table);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("FlatTypeById", "Home", new {id = ViewBag.Id })",
                async: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    var table = "<tr>";
                    $.each(data.data, function (index, value) {
                        table += "<td>" + value + "</td>";
                        console.log(value);
                    });
                    table += "</tr>";

                    $("#myData").html(table);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead id="myColumns"></thead>
        <tbody id="myData"></tbody>
    </table>
```

Example Image:

[See this sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6VAz.png)

Comment: Why have two requests? Just make one request and use the sub-array at index 0 as the header and the rest as the body of the table (server-side code must be adapted)!

Comment: Or even better `data` would be like: `{header: [...], body: [[...], [...], ...]}`!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Actually there are 2 query we use for other purpose Sir.

Comment: @imprezzeb for other purpose Sir.

Comment: @imprezzeb it's valid!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote  a function, **parse** that should help you begin to learn how to write functions that process these kinds of arrays:

```
function parse(data) {
    table = "<table>";

    for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
        table += "<tr>";
        for (j = 0, len2 = data[i].length; j < len2; j++) {
            table += "<td>" + data[i][j] +  "</td>";
        }
        table += "</tr>";
    }

    table += "</table>";

    return table;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("FlatType", "Home", new {id = ViewBag.Id})",
        async: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {

            $("#tableContainer").html(parse(data.data));
        }
    });
```

**OR** you could use a jQuery version of the code:

```
function parse(array) {
    $table = $("<table>");

    $(array).each(function (index, value) {
        $tr = $("<tr>");
        $(value).each(function (index, value) {
            $tr.append($("<td>").html(value));
        });
        $table.append($tr);
    });

    return $table;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("FlatType", "Home", new {id = ViewBag.Id})",
        async: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {

            $("#tableContainer").html(parse(data.data));
        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you for help Sir I like it! but I used the $.ajax({  }). How to do in ajax?

Comment: I can write a version that heavily relies on jQuery if you want, but are you getting an error when you add the code at the bottom of my post?  If so, what?

Comment: `JSON.parse` will throw an error as the data is already an object (due to the use of `dataType: "json"`). Read more about [**`jQuery.ajax`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)!

Comment: You should insert the table that is returned into a table container.  Like <div id='tableContainer'></div>

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to use `jQuery.each`, second there is no need to loop over the header object as it contains only one sub-array.

Code for the header part:

```
success: function (data) {
    // generate the header row
    var row = "<tr><td>" + data.data[0].join("</td><td>") + "</td></tr>";

    // override the current header row
    $("#myColumns").html(row);
}
```

Code for the body part:

```
success: function (data) {
    var $body = $("#myData");         // the body element
    $body.empty();                    // empty it

    data.data.forEach(function(sub) { // for each sub-array sub
        // generate the row
        var row = "<tr><td>" + data.data[0].join("</td><td>") + "</td></tr>";
        $body.append(row);            // append it to the body
    });
}
```

`join` joins the elements of an array and return a string of the elements joined with the string passed as parametter:

```js
var arr = ["hello", "nice", "world"];
var str = arr.join("*m*");
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.Each`, similar to a `for` (or more commonly `forEach`), is a looping mechanism that makes it each to loop over each element of an array.  You can use any loop-construct that makes sense (`for`, `while`, `reduce`, `forEach`, `map`) -- for your data, the `$.each` or `forEach` makes a lot of sense.

#### The idea

For your data, you're going to create a new table row (e.g., `<tr>`) for each of your arrays.  For each value (element) of that array, you're going to create a table header or table data element (e.g., `<th>` or `<td>`).

#### Another Example

Abstracting away from your AJAX calls, here's another way to create the header and data rows, using ES6's `forEach` and `map`:

```js
// setup JSON objects
let [column, data] = getJSON();

// Create Table Headers
let $thead = $('#myColumns'),
    $tr = $('<tr>');
column.data[0].forEach(col => {
  $tr.append($('<th>').html(col));
});
$thead.append( $tr );

// Create Table Rows
let $tbody = $('#myData');
data.data.forEach(row => {
  let $tr = $('<tr>');
  $tr.append(row.map(val => {
    return $('<td>').html(val);
  }));
  $tbody.append($tr);
});

function getJSON() {
  let column = {
      "data": [
        [
          "ID",
          "TYPE",
          "TOTAL",
          "1 bed room",
          "2 bed room"
        ]
      ]
    },
    data = {
      "data": [
        [
          "100",
          "Total Transaction Amount",
          "9812355000",
          "23397000",
          "13976000"
        ],
        [
          "100",
          "No. of units",
          "1268",
          "3",
          "2"
        ],
        [
          "100",
          "(Total sq.ft.)",
          "",
          "",
          ""
        ],
        [
          "100",
          "Avg. price",
          "7738450",
          "7799000",
          "6988000"
        ],
        [
          "100",
          "Avg. sq.ft.",
          "",
          "",
          ""
        ],
        [
          "100",
          "Max. price",
          "25494000",
          "9918000",
          "7318000"
        ],
        [
          "100",
          "Max. sq.ft",
          "",
          "",
          ""
        ],
        [
          "100",
          "Min. price",
          "5904000",
          "6465000",
          "6658000"
        ],
        [
          "100",
          "Min. sq.ft",
          "",
          "",
          ""
        ]
      ]
    };
  return [column, data];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead id="myColumns"></thead>
  <tbody id="myData"></tbody>
</table>
```

#### AJAX

If you wanted to include AJAX, the same example (without adjusting much of your original) might look something like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("FlatType", "Home", new {id = ViewBag.Id})',
    async: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      // Create Table Headers
      let $thead = $('#myColumns'),
          $tr = $('<tr>');

      data.data[0].forEach(col => {
        $tr.append($('<th>').html(col));
      });

      $thead.append($tr);
    }
  });
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("FlatTypeById", "Home", new {id = ViewBag.Id })',
    async: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      // Create Table Rows
      let $tbody = $('#myData');
      data.data.forEach(row => {
        let $tr = $('<tr>');
        $tr.append(row.map(val => {
          return $('<td>').html(val);
        }));
        $tbody.append($tr);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you Sir your answer is correct but I can't understand. Can you use include ajax()?

Comment: @PaulGeorge included

Comment: Sir, how to handle null if null then 0 zero then the output remove the header or column header.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking.  You can insert `if (col === null) return;` above the `$tr.append(` line in the header section, if you don't want to create a header cell when there isn't a value.